# Limiting Results from an Array of values

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, custom-fields

I am using advanced custom fields in Wordpress. Without going into the details of how it works, I have a "repeater field" which lets the users add as many images to an aera of the backend as they please. To show these images, I use the following code (inside wordpress loop)

```
<?php if(get_field('slider_images')): ?>
<?php while(the_repeater_field('slider_images')): ?>
     <?php 
     $attachment_id = get_sub_field('work_slider_image'); 
     $size = "homepage";  
     $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size ); 
     echo $image[0]; 
     ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

The goal here is to create an array of image URLS and to only display the FIRST one. On other pages they will all be used, but on this page, I want to grab ONLY the first image, hence the `echo $image[0];`

For some reason, it is showing all of the uploaded images, and when I print the variable $image, it returns:

```
Array ( [0] => http://sitename.com/agsinfo/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/1.jpg [1] => 392 [2] => 165 [3] => )
```

After seeing this, it would make sense to me that `echo $image[0];` would work, but for some reason its not. Any ideas?

Comment: var_dump($image); what does that return?

Comment: array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(61) "http://sitename.com/agsinfo/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/1.jpg"
  [1]=>
  int(392)
  [2]=>
  int(165)
  [3]=>
  bool(false)
}

Comment: the above repeats for each image but with different URLS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php if(get_field('slider_images')): ?>
<?php while(the_repeater_field('slider_images')): ?>
     <?php 
     $attachment_id = get_sub_field('work_slider_image'); 
     $size = "homepage";  
     $image[] = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size ); 

     ?>
<?php endwhile;
 echo $image[0];
 endif;  ?>
```

Comment: this spits out an array, I need it to spit out the FIRST image URL

Comment: oh ya [0][0] will do it , i was only pointing out that you keep overwriting your array with the last loop

Comment: This is repeating the same image for every single project...regardless if that image is in the project. It looks like it is using the same array every time wordpress loops through a project

Comment: I will say, it is displaying the correct image for the first project it loops through, and then everyone after that displays the exact same image...

Comment: im a bit confused with the little bit of code, but if there is another loop outside this code, you should reinitialize the array before starting your new loop

Comment: There is the standard wordpress loop outside of this code, which loops through 9 times, which returns 9 project photos. The idea is to have 9 unique images (the first image in each project image array)

Comment: Ahh reinitializing the array did it!